# Fluid simulation Question about the min/max of the velocity

Tags: modifiers, particles, fluid-simulation

With the fluid sism, I want to bake a simulation where i swap them out with particles. The simulation however does not have a lot of intense and high velocity movement. This causes my particle shader, that has a color and emission in it. To be barely be visible.

I tried increasing the start velocity, turbulance and de/increasing the particle amount to see if there is any change but it doesn't without ruining the flow and motion i need.

So, is there a way to redefine the maximum value of velocity for flow particles so the tranistion between moving and not moving particle increases? I haven't been able to find anything regarding this online or in the settings

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind! fixed it!

for those in the future with the similar problem. after the particle info node in the shader, simpply add a math node, use multiply.